# jQuery validate plugin: validate on blur() by default

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Okay, so I get that [jQuery Validate is opinionated](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-a-few-things-to-look-out-for-when-playing-around-with-the-demo) about when (not) to validate on `blur`:

> Before a field is marked as invalid, the validation is lazy: Before submitting the form for the first time, the user can tab through fields without getting annoying messages – they won't get bugged before having the chance to actually enter a correct value

**Is there a way to override this behavior?** I want each field to be validated whenever it loses focus, not just after there's an error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

jQuery Validation is "Lazy" validation by default.  This means that, before the submit is clicked the first time, much of the validation is ignored when moving from field to field.

You're requesting "Eager" validation, so simply over-ride the `onfocusout` default with a custom function...

```
$('#yourForm').validate({
    // rules, options, etc.,
    onfocusout: function(element) {
        // "eager" validation
        this.element(element);  
    }
});
```

**Documentation**: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onfocusout

**Additional Reference**:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28114269/594235

**Default `onfocusout` function**:

```
onfocusout: function(element) {
    // "lazy" validation by default
    if (!this.checkable(element) && (element.name in this.submitted || !this.optional(element))) {
        this.element(element);
    }
},
```

Comment: Oh wow. So simple! I actually just dove into the code and figured out this exact solution...so I'm going to post my own identical answer and accept it.

Comment: just kidding. Accept for you!