# jquery validation plugin on blur

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

Friends i am new to javascripting & jQuery and need your your help to solve 2 problems. I am using **jquery validation plugin** https://jqueryvalidation.org for a project which contains multiple forms on different pages.

**PROBLEM #1**

I included a custom JS file which already has the

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //some codes
});
```

To execute this plugin with different properties on different pages it is required to initialize it in document.ready i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#theForm").validate();
});
```

so is it ok to have document ready 2 times this way?

**PROBLEM #2**

This plugin works after the submit button is clicked. I want it to also validate **onblur** for input fields. It do have the property to validate on **onfocusout** also but that also works to handle errors after the submit button is clicked. 
So is there anyway to make the validations to also work on **blur or focusout** before the submit button is clicked?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you friends in advance.

Comment: *"So is there anyway to make the validations to also work on blur or focusout before the submit button is clicked?"*  ~ Yes, the plugin utilizes "lazy" validation and you prefer "eager" validation.  There is an easier solution for this than a custom `blur` handler that manually manipulates classes.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521336/jquery-validate-plugin-validate-on-blur-by-default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to validate on blur:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $theForm = $("#theForm"),
        $form = $theForm.validate();
    //changed to check every textbox type input inside #theForm:
    $theForm.on("blur", "input[type='text']", function(e){
        //use element() to test only one element:
        if ($form.element(this)) {
            console.log("is valid");
        }
    });

});
```

> Validator.form()
>
> Description: Validates the form, returns true if it is valid, false
>   otherwise.

---

> Validator.element( element )
>
> Description: Validates a single element, returns true if it is valid,
>   false otherwise.

More info:

https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.form/

https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element/

Working example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wPOrrx

Comment: friend its not working.

Comment: Do you have an error? Does your input have the id "myInput"?  Show your work.

Comment: I've changed it to check on *every* input of type `text` inside your form.  Make sure your form really has `id="theForm"` as an attribute.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NwJadB

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wPOrrx

Comment: friend your code is working now but as soon as a blur happens on any field... it validates the entire form

Comment: Updated to validate only a single element

Comment: so sorry friend, must be a wrong click by mistake. your answer is correct and i am using your code. thanks once again

Comment: no friend ... my vote is on up to your answer and in case there was some error on the site i did it again.

Comment: it was orange before also and still is orange. maybe someone else down voted your answer

Comment: Why is this being voted down!?

Comment: maybe because of being a duplicate question

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and yes. You can have any `$(document).ready();` on your page. It is need when you define your methods, functions before elements are rendered in DOM.

If you put your javascript at very bottom of your page (after your html element has rendered) you can leave that.

For example, in this case it needs:

```
<script>
   //before create the element
   $(function() { //same as document ready
       $('#element').on('click', function () {
          alert('Hi');
       });
   });
</script>

<div id="element">some text</div>
```

but in this case not:

```
<div id="element"></div>
<script>
   //Your element has already rendered
   $('#element').on('click', function () {
      alert('Hi');
   });
</script>
```

and you can use your validation on blur.

```
$('#myInput').on('blur', function() {
   $("#theForm").validate();
});
```

These are the basics, when you manipulate DOM by javascript, that is another story.

Comment: `$(document)`, not `$.(document)`

Comment: @SeanKendle Fixed, thx.

Comment: @vaso123 thanks friend but your blur function is not working. $("#theForm").validate(); just tells which from to validate, while the validation still happens after the submit button is clicked. I want the validations to ALSO happen even on blur or focusout

Comment: It should. You should change you `#myInput` to the input you want to check. If you want to check more inputs, add a class to those inputs, and validate on those classes. Please read the event handlers, and selectors.

Comment: You have to put those listeners in a `$(document).ready()` function.  If the elements are not already in the DOM, the listeners won't be set. A better bet is to target a parent element that is definitely in the DOM (this is also necessary if they're dynamically created by JS), like this `$(document).on("blur", "#myInput", function(e){`

Comment: @vaso123  friend the .validate(); is to tell the script which elements to validate but it still only validates after the submit button is clicked.  .validate(); command do to start the validation process