# jquery validation plugin with multiple forms and validation on blur

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am stuck in a problem and very confused. I am using jQuery validation plugin https://jqueryvalidation.org/ for multiple forms.

**PROBLEM 1:** My script to validate on blur was working fine until there was a single form to validate on each page but now it is focused on the first form it could find.

**PROBLEM 2:** When clicking the Submit button in the second or other forms, it validates all the forms instead of just validating the current form.

**SAMPLE HTML**

```
<form id="theForm" class="formContainer">
<div class="formbox formbox-33">
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" class="inputField required">
    <label class="float-label">First Name:</label>
</div>
<button type="Submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>

    <form id="theForm2" class="formContainer">
<div class="formbox formbox-33">
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" class="inputField required">
    <label class="float-label">First Name:</label>
</div>
<button type="Submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
// Initializing the forms present on current page
    $("#theForm").validate();
    $("#theForm2").validate();
});
</script>
```

**JQUERY SCRIPT**

```
var $theForm = $(".formContainer"),
$form = $theForm.validate();

$theForm.on('blur', '.inputField', function(e){
        if( $(this).hasClass("errorMessage") && $(this).parent().not( "invalid" ) ) {
            $( this ).parent().addClass(" invalid");
            $( this ).parent().removeClass("inputValid");
        }
        if( $(this).hasClass("valid") ) {
            $( this ).parent().addClass(" inputValid");
            $( this ).parent().removeClass("invalid");
        }
    });
```

Friends I can't use IDs for forms or submit buttons because any page can have one or more forms in it.

The Reset button function is working fine but same technique is not showing results when used for input fields on blur and on submit buttons.

**RESET BUTTON FUNCTION**

```
$( ".button-reset" ).click(function() {

        var parentFinder = '#' + $(this).parents('.formContainer').attr("id");
        var $FormReseter = $(parentFinder).validate();
        $FormReseter.resetForm();
        $(parentFinder + " .inputValid").removeClass("inputValid");
        $(parentFinder + " .invalid").removeClass("invalid");

    });
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It took a while to decipher what you really wanted:  to change the default "lazy" validation behavior into "eager" validation.  Closed as duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29521408/594235

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution, using the main form class in each loop. it seems to work but if you friends can comeup with a better solution it will be great

```
$(".formContainer").each(function(i, obj) {
        $form = $(this).validate();
$(this).on('blur', '.inputField', function(e){
        if( $(this).hasClass("errorMessage") && $(this).parent().not( "invalid" ) ) {
            $( this ).parent().addClass(" invalid");
            $( this ).parent().removeClass("inputValid");
        }
        if( $(this).hasClass("valid") ) {
            $( this ).parent().addClass(" inputValid");
            $( this ).parent().removeClass("invalid");
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Be aware that you're attaching `.validate()` to the same form more than once.    In addition to your class selector above, you also have `$("#theForm").validate()` and `$("#theForm2").validate()` on page load.   Only the first instance attached to any single form is used, and any subsequent attempt to initialize on the same form will be ignored.  In other words, one of your instances is superfluous and should be removed.

Comment: friend this was how i saw in the demo at the plugin site when using multiple forms on same page. about calling `.validate()` many times .. what can be done to prevent this?

Comment: Don't be confused about what I'm saying.  Using `.each()` to invoke `.validate()` on *multiple* forms is perfectly fine.  However, you're attaching `.validate()` to both the `id` and `class` of the **SAME** form at two different times <- this is what I'm talking about.  One of those two instances, whichever comes second, will be ignored... so it's pointless and will lead to future confusion.

Comment: so instead of `$(this).on("blur", ' i should use `$form.on('blur'`for each input type fields?

Comment: Geez, that has absolutely nothing to do with what I'm trying to tell you.  Look at `.validate()` and ONLY `.validate()`.  It can only be attached to ONE form at a time.  You however are doing it TWICE on every form!  Once inside your ready event handler and then once again inside your `.each()`.

Comment: And come to think of it, I have no idea why you think you need this `blur` event handler... the plugin already handles the `focusout` event and automatically adds/removes the classes as needed.

Comment: on blur to style the form with some css animations. focusout works after once submit button is clicked to remove the errors.

Comment: The plugin adds/removes classes upon validation ***automatically*** !  If you wanted to tweak that a bit, you simply need to provide custom `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions.

Comment: @Sparky just ran into the worst problem of them all. this plugin validates all fields insteaf of just the required ones :(

Comment: No it does not!  It only validates the ones where you've assigned rules.  However, your little custom script would be the root cause of the new problem you're describing

Comment: @Sparky no friend its the plugin defaults .. the tutorial i saw said to add the class 'required' to any input for it to validate, however the plugin works the other way round ..it validates all fields unless u set rules or set defaults with ignore rule. I am posting a question for it now.

Comment: I've answer a couple thousand questions about this plugin and you sound a bit confused or misled by an online tutorial.  This plugin will absolutely NOT validate anything unless you've assigned a rule via the `rules` object, via a `class`, via an HTML5 attribute, etc.  Apparently, you've assigned some rules without knowing it.  You should not need to tell it to ignore anything!

Comment: @Sparky it do validate all fields, it just dont display error on them all. if u inspect the HTML after clicking submit button u will see it adds a class `valid` to fields that are ok according to it.

Comment: And again that is only an issue for your custom code.  Assigning a `valid` class to something is **not** equivalent to validating it!  If no rules are assigned, then no rules are broken, and the field would be "valid".  Without your custom code, simply having a class in the markup means nothing.  I would suggest to remove your custom code and work within the callback functions and parameters of the plugin... your life will be easier.  Otherwise, rewrite your custom code to only target your relevant fields.

Comment: @Sparky its not just the rules .. i decorated the forms against the class valid because this is the same class it is using once it validates any element. why is it even toying with other fields

Comment: The real question is "why are you toying with `blur` and adding/removing classes" outside the confines of the plugin?", which already does this automatically.  You've gone this far, so you might as well rewrite the rest of it to your specification.  I'll await your new question before commenting further.

Comment: @Sparky I already removed all my codes so there is no blur event. should i remove all my CSS also? or should i simply forget about highlighting the fields that were required and filled correctly?

Comment: I went back and looked at some of your older questions.  Now I understand why you're doing this.  You don't like the default "lazy" validation and prefer to force it to be "eager".  Please see this for a much simpler solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29521408/594235

Comment: @Sparky this is really a good reference to make code efficient .. thanks friend .. but the default behavior of the plugin for adding 'valid' class to all fields is still a problem, i might have to force remove that class either by adding ignore rule or more custom codes :(

Comment: Since you can make any jQuery selector you want, it's still very unclear why you care about this `valid` class.  You could simply make a jQuery selector that ignores `valid` entirely.  Again, I'm going to stop commenting and wait for your new question.