# jQuery validate not binding to keyup events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm making a "contact me" page, with jQuery validation. My main content box is reloaded with ajax to change content when the user clicks on a new page. The problem I'm having now is to bind an event handler for the validate function. what I got now is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').bind('focus focusout keyup', function() {
        $('#contact_me').validate({
```

But it's not working like intended. I have to start typing, then click out of the input field and then click on it again before it starts to validate the input field value. I want it to validate on focus, `focusout` and `keyup`. I think the problem is with the event handler somehow. Any suggestions?

Here is a JSfiddle with the script: https://jsfiddle.net/z6h9d028/4/

I can see now that the eventhandler is not the problem. When i type in a input field its not validating the value until i click out of the box. After the first validation i works on keyup as well. How can i get i to work on keyup stright away?

**Edit 2:**
Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z6h9d028/7/

It's almost working now! I just need to get all the error messages to show when clicking the submit button. And to find a way to show the error message when you type one character and then remove it if the input field is required (it does show it if you type once, then remove, type again and remove. but not the first time)

Comment: yeah i tryed it now, same result.

Comment: Looking at all the examples on the [jQueryValidation docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) it seems that running on input blur is how they all work, so not sure how to override that

Comment: In fact, you don't even need your event handler stuff surrounding the validate function. It seems to add the event handlers itself.

Comment: Although *also* according to the docs, you can set the param `keyup: false` to remove keyup validation, which would suggest that the default is that it *does* do it.

Comment: Yeah my understanding also was that keyup: true was the default value.

Comment: @Rajohan Just as a note regarding editing questions, please don't modify your original question so that comments and answers don't make sense in regards to it. Ie, put your updated findings at the end of the question, but don't delete the original content. Imagine someone coming from Google, they will want to see something that helps them too in the context of the question title/content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set your own event listeners, or at least if you do, you shouldn't be using them on the `.validate()` method (see alternative method below).

Remove the whole `$('body').bind()` part, and add the following to your validate settings object:

```
onkeyup: function(element) {
  $(element).valid();
  // As sparky mentions, this could cause infinite loops, should be this:
  // this.element(element);
},
```

This should be better too, as it may give you some extra freedom as to how you handle the onkeyup events, such as adding a setTimeout if you don't want it to be instantaneous.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z6h9d028/5/

Inside the `onkeyup`, you can also call `$('#contact_me').valid()`, which will revalidate the whole form, although that may not be your desired outcome.

**Edit:** Sparky also helpfully mentioned that jquery-validate by default does allow keyup events, but it only does so after the first submit: [jQuery validate plugin: validate on blur() by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521336/jquery-validate-plugin-validate-on-blur-by-default/29521408#29521408)

---

An alternative way would be to set the details of your validation as you currently are, without the `onkeyup` function, then set your own listeners and run `$(element).valid()`:

```
$('#contact_me').validate({
  rules: {
    // ...
  }
});

$('input').on('focus focusout keyup', function () {
  $(this).valid();
});
```

---

#### Edit regarding your other issues:

Your `errorPlacement` function is doing some funky things. How it decides what is the next sibling or not seems to be working incorrectly. Also, you're adding the error HTML divs into your DOM manually, but they are actually generated by the plugin. So really, you're creating both, then trying to show them, kinda over-riding the plugin, kinda not, and the whole thing is going into a frenzy.

The solution is, I reckon, to remove those error divs, remove that `errorPlacement` function, and then modify the CSS selectors to get any id ending with "-error", which is what the plugin generates. So `[id$='-error']` instead of `.error_message`

https://jsfiddle.net/z6h9d028/8/

Comment: Thats working alot better! The error message dont show before you click out of the box tho, but that might not be possible.

Comment: Good point, let me think about it some more and I'll see if I can do that...

Comment: Hm, it shows the popup for me. I just needed to type more than one letter for some reason.

Comment: Yeah i realized that to. the email box is working becouse it got more rules then just required.

Comment: I can't get the textarea to show the error message in your original either. Also the send button requires several clicks to even show anything, so I think there are a number of other issues not related to the keyup problems unfortunately.

Comment: the textarea thing was just a naming error on the div. so its working like the others just forgot to put -error behind the name. The button ive actually not even tryed yet. Just struggled so much to get the other things working.

Comment: It appears your issue is within the `errorPlacement` function. And possibly your manual addition of those error divs. If you remove that function, remove the divs from the HTML, modify the CSS to point to the ones generated by validate, it should work: https://jsfiddle.net/z6h9d028/8/

Comment: Thanks it works perfect now!

Comment: @Rajohan Quite alright bud. Fun one to debug actually! :)

Comment: Why?  The `onfocusout` and `onkeyup` events are already handled by the plugin by default.

Comment: @Sparky No need to shout... The plugin wasn't handling it in OP's example, so what do you suggest as a reason for that?

Comment: The plugin handles it by default.  The OP probably broke it by binding `.validate()` inside of other event handlers.  So there probably isn't any need to rewrite all the default event handlers when the OP simply needed to properly initialize the plugin.

Comment: You should also remove `$(element).valid()` and replace with `this.element(element)`.  Otherwise, when you call `valid()` from within `validate()` you *could* create an infinite loop under certain circumstances.

Comment: It still doesn't work with the event handlers removed: https://jsfiddle.net/z6h9d028/9/

Comment: It works when you click the submit button first.  That's called "lazy" validation and it's also the plugin's default.  If you want to convert it to "eager" validation, then your method of overriding the `onkeyup` and `onfocusout` event handlers is appropriate.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25797083/594235 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/29521408/594235

Comment: @Sparky I didn't know that. I haven't used the plugin before, and so don't know its idiosyncrasies; I was just piecing together what I could from the docs and the fiddle, but that's useful information. I've added to my answer, thanks.

Comment: It's in the docs.  Note second bullet point:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-a-few-things-to-look-out-for-when-playing-around-with-the-demo ~ and to fully go "eager" with validation, you have to do the same to the `onfocusout` function that you did with `onkeyup`.